# Vertical lines in a polygon shapefile

Tags: python, python-2.7, shapefile, bounding-box

I am working with a GIS problem using a single input of a polygon shapefile.

Consider an irregular polygon. I want to draw vertical lines across the extent of the polygon at equal spacing.

How I intend to proceed is:

1. Identify the bounding box ***(done using PyShp)***
2. Draw vertical Lines parallel to the left edge of the bounding box at equal spacing ***(How?)***
3. Clip the lines to the extent of the polygon ***(How, without using ArcPy?)***

**Note**: They are required to be only vertical, and **not** a graticule. Also, I do not intend to use ArcPy, and intend to perform the coding completing in Python (2.7) as this segment of code needs to go into a tool generated from PyQt.

Comment: You may want to ask your question and post your code over at http://gis.stackexchange.com/ also.

Comment: Yes.. Absolutely.. Thank you :)

Comment: Any assistance with the clipping segment is most welcome..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the code to my question.. !! Thus answering it... Thank you for your inputs..

```
Ipath = raw_input("Enter the input file :- ")
Opath = raw_input("Enter the output directory :- ")
Ipath = Ipath.replace("\\", "/") # Python requirement for paths
Opath = Opath.replace("\\", "/")
copyfile(str(Ipath) + ".prj", str(Opath) + "/" + "Out_Lines" + ".prj") # Copying projection file


sf = shapefile.Reader(str('Input Path'))
shapes = sf.shapes()
Box = shapes[0].bbox
Spc = input("Enter the grid spacing :- ") # Grid Spacing read

x_min = Box[0] # Save the coordinates of the right-bottom, left-top bounding box
y_min = Box[1]
x_max = Box[2]
y_max = Box[3]

A_bbox = [x_min, y_min] # First assignment of coordinates
B_bbox = [x_max, y_max]
C_bbox = [x_min, y_max]
D_bbox = [x_max, y_min]

w = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POLYLINE) # Shapefile writer
w.line(parts = [[A_bbox, C_bbox]])
w.field('Path number', 'C', '50') 
w.record(str(1)) # Writes the first line, that is the left 'side' of the bounding box

# Increasing the X coordinate to generate a line at a specified spacing 
i = 2
while (A_bbox[0] <= x_max):
    A_bbox = [A_bbox[0] + Spc, A_bbox[1]]
    C_bbox = [C_bbox[0] + Spc, C_bbox[1]]
    w.line(parts = [[A_bbox, C_bbox]])
    w.record(str(i))
    i = i+1

w.save(str(Opath) + "/" + "Out_Lines")
```

This saves the result in a shapefile.

As a continuation to the above mentioned question, the solution of the problem is available at [Clipping Line shapefiles within extent of Polygon shape](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113799/clipping-line-shapefiles-within-extent-of-polygon-shape/113808#113808). I think that this set of questions can now be considered answered and closed.

Thank you all for your assistance.

Comment: You want it clipped to the bounding box or to the original *shape*?  One, brute force, method would be to compare points on the line with the *shape* and find where the points are *outside* the shape.

Comment: The remainder solution involving the Clipping segment is solved, and the answered is updated. Thank you for your assistance. Hope to ask many questions on this forum soon.. :)

Answer (score 0):

- Find the points/vertices that describe the line at the left edge - (x1, y1), (x2, y2)
- Add a constant to the x values - (x1+k, y1), (x2+k, y2)
- Find the y values on the polygon at the new x values - (x1+k, y3), (x2+k, y4)
- Draw the line between those two points.

Comment: Thank you very much for the input.. I will post a code soon, if its solved (or to deliberate over the errors)