# Clipping Line shapefiles within the extent of Polygon shape

Tags: python, python-2.7, line, polygon, clip

My question is an extension of [Vertical lines in a polygon shapefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25742903/vertical-lines-in-a-polygon-shapefile). Kindly refer to that question first.

What you shall see there is a method of generating vertical lines with respect to the bounding box, at user defined spacing. I understand that OGR, Fiona, Shapely etc. can be used to do the (next step of) clipping, but I am not able to understand their utilization.

How do I read one the line and polygon shapefile? Every application that uses Shapely shows how to generate the LineString, Point or Polygon but never to read and **existing shapefile**

Kindly assist me with at-least a skeleton structure so I can build on it.

Comment: I think you'd have better luck asking your question on http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a continuation to the above mentioned question, the solution of the problem is available at [Clipping Line shapefiles within extent of Polygon shape](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113799/clipping-line-shapefiles-within-extent-of-polygon-shape/113808#113808). I think that this set of questions can now be considered answered and closed.

Thank you all for your assistance.